# How to pass an intent from Adapter to Activity without intent.addFlags?

Tags: android-intent

I'm tring to pass an intent from an Adapter to an activity.
But it requires intent.addFlags of which I don't want..
Because I would like to user to navigate back to the previous activity..
Is there any better way to do that ?
Any help would be much appreciated!
thanks.

this is how it requires:

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("pid", pid);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

but I don't want to addFlags..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt there no way to do it without adding flags.
But instead of this code,

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("pid", pid);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


change it to this. problem solved !





holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Details.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pid", pid);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```